# Strange work of getDisplayMetrics()

Tags: android, screen-size

I'm writing a small application and I ran into the following problem.
When measuring the screen height in pixels, FullHD screen gives out 1920px, and FullHD + screen (2160px) gives out 2030px. What could be the problem? And is there a way to solve it without crutches (ha-ha)?

FullHD:

```
getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
>> W/Height of screen: 1920
```

FullHD+:

```
getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
>> W/Height of screen: 2030
```

Perhaps the problem is that the FullHD screen I ran in the emulator, but FullHD + is native in Xiaomi Mi Mix 2s, but in any case, it does not solve the problem.

UPD: Yes, in emulator FullHD+ screen gives out all 2160px. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

The size returned by this method (`getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels`)does not necessarily represent the actual raw size  of the display.It could include the height of the `statusbar`,and sometimes not depending on the `mobile system`.

You can get the actual height of the `activity` window by the method `getWindowsManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealmetrics(metrics)` which includs the `statusbar` always.